# filter product follow condition magento 2

Tags: magento2, collection, product-collection, condition

```
    public function getLoadedProductCollection()
    {
            $this->_limit = (int) $this->getWidgetCfg('limit');
            $type = $this->getTypeFilter();
            $fn = 'get' . ucfirst($type) . 'Products';
            $collection = $this->{$fn}();

            echo "<pre>";
            $condition = $this->getWidgetCfg('parameters');
            var_dump($condition);

            if ($this->_stockConfig->isShowOutOfStock() != 1) {
                $this->_stockFilter->addInStockFilterToCollection($collection);
            }
            $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
                'catalog_block_product_list_collection',
                ['collection' => $collection]
            );

        return $collection;
    }
```

how to use condition do a filter product list in Magento 2.please give me your answer.

this is a product list I want to filter and condition(var_dump)

[image]

Comment: Please clarify the condition which you want to apply on product list.

Comment: how to clarify the condition. That's what I'm asking. please give me your answer. if you know. thank.

Comment: Which products you want to get in product list ?

Comment: This is a list of filtered products in a different way and I want to add the filter by the condition.